# SandboxPostCopy - portal account owner must have a role: []

Tags: apex, sandbox, sandboxpostcopy

I am creating a SandboxPostCopy class that generates some mock data in our sandboxes when we do a refresh.

If I run the class via anonymous window, it works fine and builds all the goodies.

If I run the class when refreshing a sandbox, it fails with:

`First error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal account owner must have a role: []`

```
private static void createCustomerCommunityUser(String contactId) {
        try{
            User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE LastName = 'Test Customer Community User' AND IsActive = TRUE];
        }catch (QueryException qe){
            Integer randomNumber = Integer.valueOf((Math.random() * 10000));
            Profile profile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Program Productions Community'];
            User user = new User();
            user.Alias = 'standt';
            user.Email = 'standarduser8987@testorg.com';
            user.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
            user.LastName = 'Test Customer Community User';
            user.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
            user.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
            user.ProfileId = profile.Id;
            user.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
            user.Username = 'standarduser@testorg.com.smbhd' + String.valueOf(randomNumber);
            user.ContactId = contactId;
            insert user;
        }
    }
```

My research shows that **SandboxPostCopy** is ran by the **Automated Process user** who does not have a role by default.

Questions:

1. Does anyone know how to either give the Automated Process User a
   role? Along these lines, I've found how to give this user a Permission Set, but I don't know if that'll resolve the problem or not.  I can only do a refresh once every 24 hours, so I can only test so often.
2. Or how to make the SandboxPostCopy class run as a different
   user?

This is not an `@isTest` so I cannot use `System.runAs()` to run it as a different user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

- Define a Platform Event: `PostSandboxCopy__e`
- Define a trigger for this Platform Event: `PostSandboxCopyTrigger`
- [Customize the context user for the Platform Event trigger subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm) to a user other than `Automated Process`
- Have your SandboxPostCopy implementation do `EventBus.publish(new PostSandboxCopy__e(ContactId__c= xxx, ..));`
- Trigger `PostSandboxCopyTrigger` calls `createCustomerCommunityUser`

Note you'll need to define the Platform Event and change its context user, then deploy to PROD before you can do an end-end test via a sandbox copy.  You will of course, be able to unit test it before deploying to PROD

*I have not tested this, YMMV*